# How to use radare2 for a PIC32 MX534F064H

Tags: reverse-engineering, radare2

I want to reverse engine a PIC32MX534 microcontroller using radare2. It's MIPS based, main flash is at `0x1D000000` in hex file but virtual address is at `0x9D000000` and I don't know how to set this on radare2.

```
r2 -a mips cdc_com_port_single.X.production.hex
pd
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to map this file at a specific address:

```
r2 -a mips cdc_com_port_single.X.production.hex -m 0x80000000
pd
```

A bit more about mapping can be found in [Radare's book](https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/basic_commands/mapping_files.html).